# TextBox Auto Indent

Tags: .net, wpf

I'm creating a code editor, and I need auto indentation, so is there any way to add auto indentation to a textbox? For example when I press tab and write a line and then press enter, it would insert a tab and I can write directly under my last entered line. Should I manually insert the tabs or I have to use a different control? Perhaps a richtextbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a look at the [ICSharpCode text editor](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/Using%20the%20texteditor.ashx). It support almost all a modern developer's editor should support, and it can handle auto identation too. Since you are using WPF you [should start with this version](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/AvalonEdit.ashx). Even if you don't find all you want in the wiki, have a look as well since sometimes doc is not update with the real power of the component.